# style attribute not working with HSL even after bypassing sanitization in Angular

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework

I have a function to decide `background-image` which is a `linear-geadient`.

```
<div class="test-diff" [style.backgroundImage]="getBGcolor(diff)" >
```

This `getBGcolor` function decides the value based on the integer passed . I use dom sanitizer to bypass security.

```
  getBGcolor(diff){
    let style =  `linear-gradient(45deg, #fff 0%, #fff 50%, hsl(${125-25 *diff}%, 99%, 46%) 50%, hsl(${125-25 *diff}%, 100%, 50%) 100%)`;
    return this.dom.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(style);
  }
```

But the style is not being applied. Even when I give static HSL value, its not being applied. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: where is the background image here.. did you try background only. I mean [style.background] in div

Comment: Read the documents mate. You're stuffing-up the arguments. You're passing it 3 percentages. Nope - you need to pass it 1 angle and 2 percentages. Debugging the page would have shown the style with a strike-through along with the tool-tip "invalid property value" After doing this, you'd have googled for the correct format, if you didn't recall it at once.

Comment: @enhzflep I can pass how many ever percentages I want in linear gradient. The color varies with each percentage value. And No ,debugging doesnt show "invalid property" which makes me thnk its a problem of hsl with bypassing style security  . Here is the googld source for linear gradient . https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-linear-gradient/

Comment: @Shahid Im trying a triangular  background which requires linear gradient of colors so background-mage

Comment: @raj - You appear to misunderstand me. The problem is not with your gradient. The problem is in the manner you use to define the colour of one of it's stops. The gradient can have many stops, the position of these is specified with a percentage. Once a position is defined, you need to set the colour. You've chosen to use the HSL colour model. In order to specify a colour using this model, we need very different figures to the RGB model. When using HSL on the web, you need to specify an angle from 0-360 for the hue and a percentage for both the luminance and saturation channels.

Comment: (cont) - As an example, the blue colour in the scarf of your avatar picture is specified in HSL notation like this: `hsla(228,69%,24%,1)` or, without an alpha channel as `hsl(228,69%,24%)` - now then, look again at your code. You have `hsl(${125-25 *diff}%, 99%, 46%)` - See the problem now? The first figure (125-25*dif) is followed with a % symbol - this is wrong, since the first value is an angle in the range 0-360

Comment: Yes man I did misunderstand you. Thanks that was the problem. Works now. If u add it as the answr , I can accept it.